# What are these metal cylinders often found in the streets of London?

Tags: metals

I often find these metal cylinders in the streets of London: a silver-colored tube with a round tapering at one end and a hole with no thread at the other.

[image: Top view of the metal cylinder]
[image: Front view of the metal cylinder with hole]

What are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These containers are *nitrous oxide canisters*

https://www.talktofrank.com/drug/nitrous-oxide

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recreational_use_of_nitrous_oxide

Comment: I would have guessed a CO2 cartridge used in a pellet gun, but a web search shows that it's more likely sniffers(?) debris from inhaling NO2. Thumbs up for Mr. D. Duck